# Rules for a valid pool.d/www.conf file for php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

This is how I sorted my `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file after deleting all comments out of it for a nicer and easier display:

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Is this valid?

I ask this question after being stuck with [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024606/failed-to-implement-nginx-object-caching-connection-refused) without any log error to help understand what went wrong (the above sorting and deleting of  comments might be the case for the problem in the link?).